# C: Need to input my value twice after running program

Tags: c

New to programming in general. Learning from C Programming:Absolute Beginner.
Tried writing my own code from scratch and it works but I have to input my value twice for the rest of the statements to run. Can you see the issue?

EDIT: I've probably added an over complicated code to add leap year (days) on to the days already calculated. I know the answer will be a float. How ever im getting an error saying my statements specify 'double' but my arguement is 'int'. How do I convert the answer to a float?

Thanks in advance!

```
//First Practice
#include <stdio.h>

  // This simple program lets user know how many days old they are
  // by how many times Earth has rotated in relation to their age.
int main(void)
{
   int ans, age, er, leap;
   float number_of_leap_years;
   er = 365; //Earths' rotations per year
   leap = 1460;


   {
      printf("How old are you in years? \n");
      printf("Input Years: ");
      scanf("%d", &age);
   }

   if (age <=30)
   {   number_of_leap_years = (age * er) / leap;
      ans = age * er + number_of_leap_years;

      printf("You are %d days old! \n", ans);
      printf("The earth has spun %2f times since you were born!\n", ans);

   }



   else

   {
      number_of_leap_years = (age * er) / leap;
      ans = age * er + number_of_leap_years;

      printf("You are  %d days old! \n", ans);
      printf("The earth has spun %2f times since you were born!\n", ans);
      printf("Arent you dizzy??\n");


   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't realise the earth only spun once a year... it's around the sun afaik

Comment: use just `scanf("%d", &age);`

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: Looks like you have an extra set of { } around your string inputs as well.

Comment: It worked for me on the first try. You do have enter "N years old" when it asks for your age, because scanf is looking for the entire string.

Answer (score 1):

You have mistake in your line :-

```
scanf(" %d years old", &age);
```

change it to :-

```
scanf("%d", &age);
```

Modified code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>

// This simple program lets user know how many days old they are
// by how many times Earth has rotated in relation to their age.
int main(void)
{
  int ans, age, er;
  er = 365; //Earths' rotations per year

  {
    printf("How old are you in years? \n");
    printf("Input Years: ");
    scanf("%d", &age);        // no extra characters in scanf
  }

  if (age <= 30)
  {
    ans = age * er;

    printf("You are %d days old! \n", ans);
    printf("The earth has spun %d times since you were born!\n", ans);
  }
  else

  {
    ans = age * er;

    printf("You are  %d days old! \n", ans);
    printf("The earth has spun %d times since you were born!\n", ans);
    printf("Arent you dizzy??\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**Output :-**

```
How old are you in years? 
Input Years: 5
You are 1825 days old! 
The earth has spun 1825 times since you were born!
```

Why don't you take care of **leap years** ?

Comment: 'Why don't you take care of leap years' --  that would make me feel even more dizzy :-)

Comment: The code would be more maintainable (and readable) if you reorganise the logic so the age condition is simply `if(age > 30) { printf("Arent you dizzy??\n"); }` and the rest of the code proceeds it without the repetition.

Comment: Basically i need to figure out how to add a 'day' every '1460 days'?(4 years). To implement leap years into my code

Comment: @Bryon.R, it's a little more than that.  A leap year is any year evenly divisible by 4, but not 100,  or evenly divisible by both 100 and 400.